# Why array type object is not modifiable?

Tags: c, arrays, lvalue

It is stated [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarg/lvalue.htm) that

> The term modifiable lvalue is used to emphasize that the lvalue allows the designated object to be changed as well as examined. The following object types are lvalues, but not modifiable lvalues:
>
> - An array type
> - An incomplete type
> - A const-qualified type
> - A structure or union type with one of its members qualified as a const type

Because these lvalues are not modifiable, they cannot appear on the left side of an assignment statement.

Why array type object is not modifiable? Isn't it correct to write

```
int i = 5, a[10] = {0};    
a[i] = 1;
```

?
And also, what is an incomplete type?

Comment: I think change the type mean go from `int a[10]` to `double a[10] `

Comment: There's a difference between `a = value` and `a[i] = value`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assume the declaration

```
int a[10];
```

then all of the following are true:

- the type of the *expression* `a` is "10-element array of `int`"; except when `a` is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the expression will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `int`" and its value will be the address of the first element in the array;
- the type of the *expression* `a[i]` is `int`; it refers to the integer object stored as the `i`'th element of the array;
- The *expression* `a` may not be the target of an assignment because C does not treat arrays like other variables, so you cannot write something like `a = b` or `a = malloc(n * sizeof *a)` or anything like that.

You'll notice I keep emphasizing the word "expression".  There's a difference between the chunk of memory we set aside to hold 10 integers and the symbols (expressions) we use to refer to that chunk of memory.  We can refer to it with the expression `a`.  We can also create a pointer to that array:

```
int (*ptr)[10] = &a;
```

The expression `*ptr` also has type "10-element array of `int`", and it refers to the same chunk of memory that `a` refers to.

C does not treat array expressions  (`a`, `*ptr`) like expressions of other types, and one of the differences is that an expression of *array* type may not be the target of an assignment.  You cannot reassign `a` to refer to a different array object (same for the expression `*ptr`).  You *may* assign a new value to `a[i]` or `(*ptr)[i]` (change the value of each array *element*), and you may assign `ptr` to point to a different array:

```
int b[10], c[10];
.....
ptr = &b;
.....
ptr = &c;
```

As for the second question...

An *incomplete* type lacks size information; declarations like

```
struct foo;
int bar[];
union bletch;
```

all create incomplete types because there isn't enough information for the compiler to determine how much storage to set aside for an object of that type.  You cannot create objects of incomplete type; for example, you cannot declare

```
struct foo myFoo;
```

unless you complete the definition for `struct foo`.  However, you can create *pointers* to incomplete types; for example, you *could* declare

```
struct foo *myFooPtr;
```

without completing the definition for `struct foo` because a pointer just stores the address of the object, and you don't need to know the type's size for that.  This makes it possible to define self-referential types like

```
struct node {
  T key;  // for any type T
  Q val;  // for any type Q
  struct node *left; 
  struct node *right;
};
```

The type definition for `struct node` isn't *complete* until we hit that closing `}`.  Since we can declare a pointer to an incomplete type, we're okay.  However, we could not define the struct as

```
struct node {
  ... // same as above
  struct node left;
  struct node right;
};
```

because the type isn't complete when we declare the `left` and `right` members, and also because each `left` and `right` member would each contain `left` and `right` members of their own, each of which would contain `left` and `right` members of *their* own, and on and on and on.

That's great for structs and unions, but what about

```
int bar[];
```

???

We've declared the symbol `bar` and indicated that it will be an array type, but the size is unknown at this point.  *Eventually* we'll have to define it with a size, but this way the symbol can be used in contexts where the array size isn't meaningful or necessary.  Don't have a good, non-contrived example off the top of my head to illustrate this, though.

**EDIT**

Responding to the comments here, since there isn't going to be room in the comments section for what I want to write (I'm in a verbose mood this evening).  You asked:

> Does it mean every variables are expression?

It means that any variable can be an expression, or part of an expression.  Here's how the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf%E2%80%8E) defines the term *expression*:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> 1 An *expression* is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a
>  value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that
> performs a combination thereof.

For example, the variable `a` all by itself counts as an expression; it designates the array object we defined to hold 10 integer values.  It also evaluates to the address of the first element of the array.  The variable `a` can also be part of a larger expression like `a[i]`; the operator is the subscript operator `[]` and the operands are the variables `a` and `i`.  This expression designates a single member of the array, and it evaluates to the value currectly stored in that member.  That expression in turn can be part of a larger expression like `a[i] = 0`.

> And also let me clear that, in the declaration int a[10], does a[] stands for array type

Yes, exactly.

In C, declarations are based on the types of expressions, rather than the types of objects.  If you have a simple variable named `y` that stores an `int` value, and you want to access that value, you simply use `y` in an expression, like

```
x = y;
```

The type of the *expression* `y` is `int`, so the declaration of `y` is written

```
int y;
```

If, on the other hand, you have an *array* of `int` values, and you want to access a specific element, you would use the array name and an index along with the subscript operator to access that value, like

```
x = a[i];
```

The type of the *expression* `a[i]` is `int`, so the declaration of the array is written as

```
int arr[N]; // for some value N.
```

The "`int`-ness" of `arr` is given by the type specifier `int`; the "array-ness" of `arr` is given by the declarator `arr[N]`.  The declarator gives us the name of the object being declared (`arr`) along with some additional type information not given by the type specifier ("is an N-element array").  The declaration "reads" as

```
    a       -- a
    a[N]    -- is an N-element array
int a[N];   -- of int
```

**EDIT<sup>2</sup>**

And after all that, I still haven't told you the *real* reason why array expressions are non-modifiable lvalues.  So here's yet another chapter to this book of an answer.

C didn't spring fully formed from the mind of Dennis Ritchie; it was derived from an earlier language known as B (which was derived from BCPL).<sup>1</sup>  B was a "typeless" language; it didn't have different types for integers, floats, text, records, etc.  Instead, everything was simply a fixed length word or "cell" (essentially an unsigned integer).  Memory was treated as a linear array of cells.  When you allocated an array in B, such as

```
auto V[10];
```

the compiler allocated 11 cells; 10 contiguous cells for the array itself, plus a cell that was bound to V containing the location of the first cell:

```
    +----+
V:  |    | -----+
    +----+      |
     ...        |
    +----+      |
    |    | <----+
    +----+
    |    |
    +----+
    |    |      
    +----+
    |    |
    +----+
     ...
```

When Ritchie was adding `struct` types to C, he realized that this arrangement was causing him some problems.  For example, he wanted to create a struct type to represent an entry in a file or directory table:

```
struct {
  int inumber;
  char name[14];
};
```

He wanted the structure to not just describe the entry in an abstract manner, but also to represent the bits in the actual file table entry, which didn't have an extra cell or word to store the location of the first element in the array.  So he got rid of it - instead of setting aside a separate location to store the address of the first element, he wrote C such that the address of the first element would be computed when the array expression was evaluated.

*This* is why you can't do something like

```
int a[N], b[N];
a = b;
```

because both `a` and `b` evaluate to pointer *values* in that context; it's equivalent to writing `3 = 4`.  There's nothing in memory that actually *stores* the address of the first element in the array; the compiler simply computes it during the translation phase.

---

<sub>1. This is all taken from the paper [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.pdf)</sub>

Comment: You called `a` an *Expression*, and I learned that it is a *variable* or *object*. Does it mean every variables are expression? And also let me clear that, in the declaration `int a[10]`, does `a[]` stands for `array type`? I am really confused about this from the beginning I started reading arrays! Please clarify this.

Comment: You said *the "array-ness" of `arr` is given by the declarator `arr[N]`*. As a declarator is the name of object being
declared, possibly surrounded by operators
such as `*`, `[]` or `()`, Shouldn't array-ness of `arr` is given by the `[]` operator?

Comment: And also elaborate this line *In C, declarations are based on the types of expressions, rather than the types of objects*

Comment: @haccks: I said it above: *The declarator gives us the name of the object being declared (arr) **along with some additional type information not given by the type specifier** ("is an N-element array").*  `arr` is the *identifier*.  `arr[N]` is the *declarator*.

Comment: @haccks: As for declarations being based on the types of expressions, I explained that already; `arr` is an array of `int`; when the expression `arr[i]` appears in the code (such as a statement like `x = arr[i]`), that expression has a value of type `int`.  C is designed so that the form of the declaration closely matches the form of the expression in the code.  So when we declare an array, we write `T a[N];`, because the declaration `a[N]` *looks like* the expression `a[i]` in the code `x = a[i]`.

Comment: @haccks: For comparison, here's what an array declaration looks like in Ada: `arr: array (1..N) of Integer;`.  All the type information is separate from the identifier.

Comment: I did't get your line:- *but also to represent the bits in the actual file table entry, which didn't have an extra cell or word to store the location of the first element in the array.*

Comment: Shouldn't the address-of operator be used for pointer-to-array?  `int a[10]; int (*ptr)[10] = &a;`  C is forgiving here; C++ is not.  The version with correct typing (`&a`) works in both.

Comment: @JohnBode: What's the difference between type of expression and type of object? Aren't those the same thing?

Comment: @haccks a shortcut to understant that a variable name is an expression: in math `1*a` is `a`

Answer (score 6):

The term "lvalue of array type" literally refers to the array object as an lvalue of array type, i.e. array object *as a whole*. This lvalue is not modifiable as a whole, since there's no legal operation that can modify it as a whole. In fact, the only operations you can perform on an lvalue of array type are: unary `&` (address of), `sizeof` and implicit conversion to pointer type. None of these operations modify the array, which is why array objects are not modifiable.

`a[i]` does not work with lvalue of array type. `a[i]` designates an `int` object: the i-th element of array `a`. The semantics of this expression (if spelled out explicitly) is: `*((int *) a + i)`. The very first step - `(int *) a` - already converts the lvalue of array type into an rvalue of type `int *`. At this point the lvalue of array type is out of the picture for good.

*Incomplete type* is a type whose size is not [yet] known. For example: a struct type that has been declared but not defined, an array type with unspecified size, the `void` type.

Comment: I am confused with this line *`a[i]` does not work with lvalue of array type. `a[i]` modifies an `int` object.*

Comment: One thing I want to clear here........What does the declaration `int a[10]` means?

Answer (score 4):

An incomplete type is a type which is declared but not defined, for example `struct Foo;`.

You can always assign to individual array *elements* (assuming they are not `const`). But you cannot assign something to the whole array.

C and C++ are quite confusing in that something like `int a[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3};` is not an assignment but an initialization even though it looks pretty much like an assignment.

This is OK (initialization):

```
int a[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

This is does not work in C/C++:

```
int a[10];
a = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Is `int i = 1;` also not an assignment?

Comment: No, it is initialization. You can have for example also `const int i = 1;` which is valid, even though you cannot change (assign) the value of `i`.

Comment: OK. In the declaration int a[10], which one is object either `a` or `a[10]` ?

Comment: `a` is the object being initialised. The C syntax seems intuitive but is confusing. `a[10]` as a declaration or definition is something very different from `a[10]` as an expression (array indicator and size vs. array lookup).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` is an array of ints, `a[10]` isn't an array. It is an `int`.

`a = {0}` would be illegal.

Comment: And what about `a = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the value of an array is actually the address (pointer) of its first element. This address can't be modified. So

```
int a[10], b[10];
a = b
```

is illegal.

It has of course nothing to do with modifying the *content* of the array as in `a[1] = 3`

Comment: this has nothing to do with implicit conversion  to pointers (if  that's what you're referring to by the phrase "value of an array  is an address")