# Indirect array assignment works, while direct array assignment does not

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment

What is the difference between the two array assignments, one inside a struct and one outside a struct?

```
struct A
{
   char s[4];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char s[4];
   char d[4];

   d = s; // 'invalid array assignment'

   A a, b;
   b = a; // compiles without problems

   return 0;
}
```

The default operator `=` is supposed to invoke member-by-member assignment operators. If so, then there should exist an array assignment operator, but the compiler does not want to invoke it explicitly. Why?

Comment: Your "indirect array assignment" is a structure assignment, and regularly used for returning fixed-arrays from functions and passing said structures as value-params. `a.s = b.s` would obviously likewise fail.

Comment: Because C++ has its crazy side - the craziness here is that arrays are not first-class citizens of the language (e.g. they are not copyable and usually decay to pointers), and so structure copying has to have a special rule that says that array members are copied element-wise. If it weren't like this and arrays were like any other type, the structure copying rules would just say "all members are copied".

Comment: Also relevant: [Why array type object is not modifiable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17687429/2069064)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is why... Struct is a class object and there is this special rule for assignment of member its an array, not for an array itself ([c++14 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)):

> **12.8 Copying and moving class objects**
>
> 12.8.28. The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class X performs memberwise copy-
>   /move assignment of its subobjects. The direct base classes of X are assigned first, in the order of their
>   declaration in the base-specifier-list, and then the immediate non-static data members of X are assigned, in
>   the order in which they were declared in the class definition. Let x be either the parameter of the function
>   or, for the move operator, an xvalue referring to the parameter. Each subobject is assigned in the manner
>   appropriate to its type:
>
> 2. — if the subobject is an array, each element is assigned, in the manner appropriate to the element type;

So the copy procedure is not defined for an array (because it's an unmodifiable variable type), but for a member type that is an array. There is no definition for implicit `operator=` for an array.

Answer (score -2):

The value of an array name (e.g., `s`) is the starting address of the array. Once the array is allocated in memory, that address should be fixed. `d = s` is saying to assign the starting address of `s[4]` to `d[4]`, which obviously can't be done.

A simple structure like yours is just a chuck of bits. In your case, an instance of `A` occupies 4 bytes. When you do `a = b`, it copies the bits of `b` to that of `a`.

To illustrate the difference, I don't think you can do `a.s = b.s`. You can try.